# how to export Libgdx project to xcode project using intellij or eclipse?

Tags: ios, xcode, intellij-idea, libgdx

Is there any option to export libgdx ios project to xcode project. i want to add additional functionalities to the game using native code before start the game (like add a screen to display ad or splash screen), so that i need a xcode project.

i unable to find export options for xcode project in libgdx using intellij idea. i can run game directly from intellij idea but unable to export it, anyone can help me?

Comment: I looked into this before, and I don't think it's possible to do it that way. What you need to do is create a static library in Xcode, and then create a RoboVM Bro interface so you can use it from the Java side. https://github.com/robovm/robovm/wiki/The-Bro-Java-to-native-bridge

Comment: Someone has already done this work for many ad providers and shared it. See here: https://github.com/BlueRiverInteractive/robovm-ios-bindings